# Can anybody explain to me how to copy specific file types from A to B to include their folder structure?

Tags: data-transfer

I know that this has been asked and answered before, but I am home sick and my brain just cannot understand anything very well right now.  My OS is Windows, and I am looking to copy only the Exchange data from some specific folders (they are all contained within a root folder, but there are more folder layers which I would like to preserve).  In this root folder, there are also other files, which I do not want to copy.  I only want to copy the files with the extension .PST.

I have a directory listing of everything in my source location, so I can already identify the files which I want, together with their paths.

I want to copy only the PSTs into a new destination folder, but also preserve the folder structure for the PSTs.  These are approx 300 PSTs at a size of 700GBs, so I really do not want to do this manually, but I am just struggling to figure this out.

I wanted to use Robocopy, but it seems that you can only use this for folders?  I could have sworn that I used it for files before, but maybe I'm wrong.  My brain really is just dead at the moment!

Would anybody be able to explain to me, as if I was an idiot (which I am today) how I can do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try copying just the folder structure first to see is that helps.   .......   xcopy “C:\Folder_name” “D:\Folder name” /T /E     .....   The /T option copies just the folder names.

Comment: Thanks John.  That's a good idea so that at least I will have the structure.  I will give that a go for a start.  If there was a way of getting the PSTs over as well though, that would be the dream!

Answer (score 3):

Robocopy is definitely an option, and you can definitely include or exclude certain items.

In your case including specific files is easy.

```
Robocopy source destination *.pst /mir
```

Which will copy the entire directory structure and only files that match `*.pst`.

Alternatively if you only want directories that contain a matched file then the `/s` option is better than either `/mir` or `/e`.

```
Robocopy source destination *.pst /s
```

In this case you won't get empty directories in your output.

The [robocopy documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) has more information on the various options.

Comment: Thank you Mokubai.  That is exactly what I needed.  I appreciate this very much!